# Does the html5 required attribute degrade gracefully in browsers that don't support it?

Tags: html, attributes, cross-browser, graceful-degradation

I'd love to use the `required` attribute on forms, but I don't know how older browsers will deal with this attribute that is (to them) unknown.

Will older browsers nicely ignore  (and thus allow to gracefully degrade) the html5 `required` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, browsers will just ignore unknown attributes.